# dyld: Symbol not found: error in iOS 3.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.2

I am getting the following error on iOS 3.2:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSCache
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/884C05DF-261D-4581-96CD-3727103C5832/speedymap.app/speedymap
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /var/mobile/Applications/884C05DF-261D-4581-96CD-3727103C5832/speedymap.app/speedymap
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)
```

I have no clue about the `NSCache` class; I am not even using it.

Comment: You must have debugged the application. Kindly post the code where you are getting this error.

Comment: i am getting this error when i am trying to test it on device with active configuration : Released

Comment: one more thing i have just checked NSCache class and i realized that i am using objectForKey for jason parsing. so my question is can we use this function in ios 3.2 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSCache` class is available starting iOS4.0, so attempt to use it on 3.2 will result in error. If you don't use it directly - check if you use some other classes/methods (or may be 3rd-party libs) that are 4.0+ only - they may use `NSCache` internally.

Answer (score 0):

I think You may delete or update one source file which currently reference from another class